# Converting Unicode char Ids string to unicode text .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unicode, web-scraping

Im doing a web scraping project and i get a json file from the scraper , the problem is that for any lang other than english the actual unicode char ID is written for example :

it will store

```
&#1508;&#1500;&#1505;&#1496;&#1497;&#1504;&#1497;&#1501;
```

instead of

```
םויסלפנ
```

What i want to do is to input a string that stores char IDs + english text + HTML entitys ,and replace every unicode ID/HTML entity with the unicode char that fits it. Anyone knows on a method that can help me with the task? 
Using 
.NET
ASP.NET
JSON.NET
IronWebScraper

-A Bit new to stackoverflow

Edit: 
Here's Code Sample

```
  using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"DataBase\net\net.jsonl"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<string> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        foreach (var str in items)
            Logger.Log(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str));
    }
```

Comment: Hi Tomer, to get the most response on here from the community, it is customary to include a minimum reproducible example of your code so that people can cut and paste it into their editors, run it, get your output, and then write some code to generate you the output you are looking for. So also, it is helpful to be explicit in specifying the string you want to input and exactly the output you are hoping for, so that a respondent can make sure they are providing code that will help you out. If you do this, you should get good response. Thanks and good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple: just use the [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode) method:

```
var plainText = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#1508;&#1500;&#1505;&#1496;&#1497;&#1504;&#1497;&#1501;");
```

If there are any regular characters in there, they will be left alone:

```
var plainText = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("This is a Hebrew character: &#1508;");
```

That will result in:

> This is a Hebrew character: פ